# Starting more than one instance of redis with systemd and without template

Tags: systemd, redis

I am trying to start 2 instances of `redis` on different ports (`6379`, `6380`),
I have followed all the guides, examples of creating `systemd` units for `redis`
Somehow, the second instance stops **after a while with** the foll in the log:

`# User requested shutdown`

I am running `redis 5.0.5` on Ubuntu `18.04.2` with `systemd 237`.

I have tried both these combinations:

- redis config file with `daemonize yes` and `Type=forking` in `[Service]`
- redis config file with `daemonize no` and `Type=simple` in `[Service]`

(although I am not sure which one is right!)

I also tried adding `supervised systemd (Type=notify)` that didnt seem to help either!
Note that they have separate config files and separate pid files,
pids get written correctly
(specified `PIDFile=` in unit spec)

Please help!

--Edit--

After some more experimentation I found that commenting out the RDB
persistence (`dir` and `dbfilename`) made both instances come up!

In case of multiple instances what other changes do I need other than
keeping the 2 directory names and dbfile names different?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick guide with minimal duplication to run two instances using same `redis` package, though we'll be using separate a directory for `pid` and `sock` files in `/run` (`/var/run` is symlink in modern distros). Using same directory will cause conflict while stopping and restarting any of the two services.

1. **Duplicate default config:**

   `sudo cp /etc/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis4cache.conf`

   `sudo nano /etc/redis/redis4cache.conf` and change as below:

   ```
   -port 6379
   +port 6380

   # -or- if you're using socket:-

   -unixsocket /run/redis/redis-server.sock
   +unixsocket /run/redis4cache/redis4cache.sock

   -pidfile /run/redis/redis-server.pid
   +pidfile /run/redis4cache/redis4cache.pid

   -logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
   +logfile /var/log/redis/redis4cache.log

   -dbfilename dump.rdb
   +dbfilename redis4cache_dump.rdb

   -# maxmemory <bytes>
   +maxmemory 134217728 # 128MB

   +maxmemory-policy allkeys-lfu # (Least Frequently Used)
   ```
2. **Duplicate Redis Service:**

   `sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service /lib/systemd/system/redis4cache.service`

   `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/redis4cache.service` and change as below:

   ```
   -ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
   +ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis4cache.conf

   -PIDFile=/run/redis/redis-server.pid
   +PIDFile=/run/redis4cache/redis4cache.pid

   -RuntimeDirectory=redis
   +RuntimeDirectory=redis4cache

   -ReadWriteDirectories=-/run/redis
   +ReadWriteDirectories=-/run/redis4cache

   -Alias=redis.service
   ```
3. **Enable and Start services:**

   `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

   `sudo systemctl enable redis4cache`

   `sudo systemctl start redis4cache`
4. **Verify two services:**

   `ps aux | grep redis`

   `sudo redis-cli -s /run/redis/redis-server.sock`

   `sudo redis-cli -s /run/redis4cache/redis4cache.sock`